# complex htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

Before using word press for our new website we were using following urls...

```
http://www.domain.com/web-services
http://www.domain.com/seo-services  (about 100 urls)
```

Now new url would be

```
http://www.domain.com/np/web-services
```

So we would like to 301 redirect all old pages to new pages, we could simple use following htaccess code...

```
Redirect 301 /web-services http://www.domain.com/np/web-services
```

But that would make htaccess file too large, so is there any way to redirect all pages to new pages.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite on your apache server, then put this inside your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/web-services/(.*)$ /np/web-services/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/seo-services/(.*)$ /np/web-services/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any url starting with /web-services or /seo-services will be redirected to /np/web-services.

Comment: that would be simple solution, but i have to create 100 lines in htaccess file to redirect all urls

Comment: is there any way so it could check regex like if url has - then redirect to /np/$1 (would be same / keyword)

Comment: why? Those lines will redirect any url beginning with /web-services or /seo-services. So there is no need to create 100 lines! those 2 lines are enough

Comment: i think you didn't get, url structure was http://www.domain.com/page1, http://www.domain.com/page2 and so on.(about 100) i just want to target only urls like www.domain.com/seo-services (contains -)

Comment: Just to let you figure out: the url /seo-services/foo will be redirected with HTTP/301 to /np/web-services/foo and the url /web-services/foo will be redirected to /np/web-services/foo. If you call /seo-services/bar you will be redirected to /np/web-services/bar

Comment: i know but it could be anything after / so we can't predefine /webs-services etc.

Comment: OK. So you want to redirect any page to /np/? Example: /foo --> /np/foo ?

Comment: yes only those ends up with /$keyword-$keword (any regex to check)

Comment: Try this one: RewriteRule (^[^-/]+)-([^-/]+) /np/$1-$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: its redirecting but putting too many /np/np/np/np/np/ in url after i used `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^[^-/]+)-([^-/]+)-([^-/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively, you can use mod_alias' `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^\-]+)-([^/]+)/?(.*)?$ /np/$1-$2/$3
```

So any request that starts with `/web-services/` will get redirected with a `/np` appended to the front:

```
http://www.example.com/web-services/test1 -> http://www.example.com/np/web-services/test1
http://www.example.com/web-services/test/test2 -> http://www.example.com/np/web-services/test/test2
```

And the same with seo-services or anything with XXX-XXX.

---

EDIT:

> if i try `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^\-]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3/` its thorwing redirection error

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/\-]+)-([^/\-]+)-([^/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3/
```

Because `/np/` is being matched against `^/([^\-]+)`

Comment: you mean if any old like http://www.domain.com/web-design-services would be redirect to http://www.domain.com/np/web-design-services would it check only 2 - or 3-? as i need 3 - as all urls have xxx-xxx-xxx   thanks for great support and help. :)

Comment: For three you would have to expand @Jon Lin's code to: ([^\-]+)-([^/]+)-([^\-]+)/(.*)$ /np/$1-$2-$3/$4

Comment: thanks for great help, its not working, it throwing 404 even its not redirecting urls to new urls i have tried http://www.domain.com/web-design-services and nothing happened. please check thanks.

Comment: `domain.com/web-design-services` won't match the regular expression because it wasn't clear it was what you wanted. If you want to be able to redirect without anything after the match, you have to include that in the regular expression, See the edit.

Comment: it thrown 'The page isn't redirecting properly - firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.'

Comment: i have tried following rule `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^\-]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3/`

Comment: as all required urls would be domain.com/xxx-xxx-xxx

Comment: all old urls end with /xxx-xxx-xxx for example http://www.domain.com/web-design-services needs to be redirected to http://www.domain.com/np/web-design-services, but if i try `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^\-]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+) /np/$1-$2-$3/` its thorwing redirection error

Comment: its working now, but added too many np in url like `http://www.domain.com/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/np/web-design-services`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewite your domin like as if your domin was open with abc.com then you can permanently redirect it with www.abc.com. By doing this you can make sure that when google spider visit on your site then it can easily find your site. It also helps to increase more traffic on your site. If you have a busieness website then you can use SEO service from a company in Los Angeles going through reviews of best SEO Company in Chicago. Because these are helps to always push up your business growth towards top. Origin : http://www.bestseocompanyreviewss.com.